Is anyone *successfully* using Privoxy on 24.04 or 24.10?
I installed Privoxy from the standard built-in repository. I rebooted. It is running. I have set my proxy settings, in the system control panel, and in my browsers. It is being ignored, in Waterfox and Firefox and Chrome.
Are any additional steps needed?
I checked it was running with:
# systemctl status privoxy.service
● privoxy.service - Privacy enhancing HTTP Proxy
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/privoxy.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-10-22 08:57:22 BST; 3h 17min ago
 Invocation: 5818a3185ae04647ac4288d6ecdd30e0
       Docs: man:privoxy(8)
             https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/
   Main PID: 1725 (privoxy)
      Tasks: 38 (limit: 28537)
     Memory: 10.7M (peak: 13.9M)
        CPU: 7.164s
     CGroup: /system.slice/privoxy.service
             └─1725 /usr/sbin/privoxy --pidfile /run/privoxy.pid --user privoxy /etc/privoxy/config

````



Can you check with wget if the proxy is functional? wget --server-response https://ubuntu.com/ -e use_proxy=on -e https_proxy=https://127.0.0.1:8118 should return headers. Also if you set debug=512 in /etc/privoxy/config and restart the service, you should see log entries in /var/log/privoxy/logfile

That got me 117.8kB of index.html: 2024-10-23 09:40:26 (3.09 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [120705/120705] It looks valid. I've added the debug thing and will watch.

Interesting development. Today, Privoxy started working on Chrome, which I discovered by a domain-not-found error. Going to http://privoxy.org/config still does not work and says it is not in use. It is still not working in Firefox/Waterfox.
